# Safe to store bike with no coolant?

Tags: motorcycle, coolant, winter

I'm storing my track bike, a first gen SV650, over the winter. The coolant is distilled water and Water Wetter. The storage is heated, but I'd just as soon not worry about their losing power or whatever. This is coastal Maine, it'll be below freezing for a couple weeks at a time.

So: Would it be safe just to drain the coolant and store it that way, or should I replace it with antifreeze? It might be nice to save myself the trouble of flushing it in the spring, if there's zero chance it'll do do my bike any harm.

Comment: If your not looking at temps below -40 where the bike is stored.  Then look at a power sport waterless coolant.  The stuff is one time replacement then in for life of the bike.

Comment: @spicetraders Is it allowed on racetracks?

Comment: I know Evans has several versions and list one as race track coolant for cars where a "No Ethylene Glycol" rules are in place.   As well as the Powersports version shows race bikes.  Between the technical spec sheet and contacting the manufacturer should confirm it will meet the areas tracks rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Draining it and leaving it empty will promote rust formation inside your cooling system. I'd fill it with antifreeze, as it also contains corrosion inhibitors.

Comment: Are there steel/iron parts of the cooling system on that bike?

Comment: @Dlu.  Yes, steel sleeves with water jackets behind them.

Comment: Thanks. That leads to a second question: The cooling system is full of water already. Is it just that it's distilled water in a (more or less) closed system?